# Detecting input white space to use in an if statement

Tags: c++, whitespace

I am trying to create a c++ program that detects when white space has been input to a `cin` line, and then detects what word comes after it.
I am only showing my function here:

```
int lineFunction (string line) {
   if (/*whatever characters, then whitespace, and the letter ‘a’ is read*/) {
      return 0;
   }else if (/*whatever characters, then whitespace followed by the letter ‘b’*/) {
      return 1;
   }else {
      return 2;
   }
}
```

So if the input is, say: `abc a` then the output should be 0, and if the input is `abc b` then the output should be 1, otherwise it should be 2.
I would also like to know if this function could be ‘stacked’, like if I could have multiple white spaces and multiple words.

Comment: Well, you don’t need to write out a whole function, just lead me in the right direction, in terms of detecting whitespace.

Comment: Did you try doing any research? [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) coupled with [`std::isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)?

Comment: The most portable method is to read a line of text into a string, then manipulate the string.  Otherwise use OS API to read the keystrokes and ignore the whitespace.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius How would you use both of them, to detect whitespace followed by a word?

Comment: First of all you have to precisely define what you want to do? For example, you can trim space at end, check if the length is at least 2 and then verify if the second last character is a space and then test last character. This would work if you want last word when it is single letter. The best thing to do is to draw an organigram or write pseudo-code first and then implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [std::isspace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int lineFunction(std::string line) {
    auto begin = std::find_if(std::begin(line), std::end(line), [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); });
    if (begin == std::end(line) || ++begin == std::end(line)) return 2;
    auto end = std::find_if(begin, std::end(line), [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); });
    std::string word(begin, end);
    if (word == "a") {
        return 0;
    } else if (word == "b") {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
} 

int main() {
    std::string line = "abc a";
    std::cout << lineFunction(line);
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation, and the example, that you link to? `// static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isspace)         // wrong`